# When I program in Linux using C, I use the open or creat functions and end up behaving differently

Tags: c, linux

```
//error handle
void my_err(const char* errno_string,int line){
    fprintf(stderr,"line:%d ",line);
    perror(errno_string);
    exit(1);
}

//self-definded read data function

int my_read(int fd){
    int len;
    int ret;
    int i;
    char read_buf[64];

    //get length of file and keep point of file at the srart
    if(lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END) == -1){
        my_err("lseek",__LINE__);
    }

    if((len = lseek(fd,0,SEEK_CUR)) == -1){
        my_err("lseek",__LINE__);
    }

    if(lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET) == -1){
        my_err("lseek",__LINE__);
    }

    printf("len:%d\n",len);

    //read data
    if((ret = read(fd,read_buf,len)) < 0){
        my_err("read",__LINE__);
    }

    //print data
    for(i = 0;i<len;i++){
        printf("%c",read_buf[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char write_buf[32] = "hello boy!";

    //create example2 in current directory
    if((fd = creat("example2.c",S_IRWXU)) == -1){
    // if((fd = open("example2.c",O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,S_IRWXU)) == -1){
        my_err("open",__LINE__);
    }else{
        printf("craete file success\n");
    }

    //write data
    if(write(fd,write_buf,strlen(write_buf)) != strlen(write_buf)){
        my_err("write",__LINE__);
    }
    my_read(fd);

    //Spacing of presentation files
    printf("/*------------*/\n");
    if(lseek(fd,10,SEEK_END) == -1){
        my_err("lseek",__LINE__);
    }
    if(write(fd,write_buf,strlen(write_buf)) != strlen(write_buf)){
        my_err("write",__LINE__);
    }
    my_read(fd);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

> Line 43 is this part of main

```
    //create example2 in current directory
    if((fd = creat("example2.c",S_IRWXU)) == -1){
        my_err("open",__LINE__);
    }else{
        printf("craete file success\n");
    }
```

When I use **creat**, I get an error line:43 read: Bad file descriptor, but I get the correct result with **open**. Shouldn't both functions return file descriptors? Why should creat return the **wrong file descriptor**

When I use **creat**, I get an error line:43 read: Bad file descriptor, but I get the correct result with **open**. Shouldn't both functions return file descriptors? Why should creat return the **wrong file descriptor**
[image]

Comment: 1. Please use preformatted text for terminal output rather than a screnshot. 2. We don't know where line 43 is, please mark it if you refer to it.

Comment: Your `my_err` function is flawed. `fprintf` can set `errno` so calling it before the `perror` means that the `perror` may be printing `errno` that was modified by `fprintf`. Fix that first to confirm the actual `creat` error (the [creat man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/creat) does not show that error as a posibility).

Comment: From the man page: "`creat()` is equivalent to `open()` with `flags` equal to `O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC`." Notice it is `O_WRONLY` not `O_RDWR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't both functions return file descriptors?

They should and they do.

> Why should creat return the wrong file descriptor

It shouldn't and it doesn't. `read` fails with `Bad file descriptor` error, not `creat`.

`creat` opens file write-only, so you can't read from it. It's a bad file descriptor if you want to read from it.

Answer (score 1):

The call `creat(path, mode)` behaves the same as the call `open(path, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, mode)`. On success, the file is opened for writing only. The file descriptor passed to `read` needs to be open for either reading and writing or for reading only. If the file descriptor is open for writing only, calls to `read` with that file descriptor will fail. When `read` fails, the error number `EBADF` means that the file descriptor is not a valid file descriptor open for reading.